# Testing write-rate limits on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing

I have some code in which I'm worried I'll occasionally exceed write-rate limits. Is there a way to specify in, for example, `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig`, what write-rate limits should be enforced on the test server?

Alternatively, is there a way I can install a callback that will enforce its own write rules?  I'd be happy enough just to throw an error the second time a given entity is put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mock objects to record a certain behavior for objects in your test run. (e.g. throwing exception during the second invocation of the datastore put)

I use [easy mock](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html) for my app engine unit tests, might be worth a look to see if it's suitable for your testing.